# How can I create a keymap that shifts focus to a split window and maximizes its width and height?

Tags: vim, keymaps

I use split windows in Vim, and I have the following keymap in my .vimrc:
`nnoremap <C-l> <C-w>l`
This makes it possible for me to use `CTRL-l` to focus on the window to the right. However, I still have to maximize its width and height with `CTRL-w |` and `CTRL-w _`.

To achieve this, I tried modifying my keymap so that pressing `CTRL-l` focuses on the window to the right and maximizes its width and height. My first attempt was `nnoremap <C-l> <C-w>l<C-w>|<C-w>_`, but this resulted in an error. Next, I tried to only increase the width of the window to the right after shifting focus to it `nnoremap <C-l> <C-w>l<C-w>|` This does not produce an error, but it also does not increase the width of the window to the right (after shifting focus to it). What am I doing wrong in my keymap?

I know that I can make the current window the only one on the screen with CTRL-w_o, but this is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: You can't use a `|` in a mapping without either escaping it: `<C-w>\|` or using `<bar>` instead. See `:help map-bar`.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.